# SwiftUI 5.5 Init array with substring of string?

Tags: arrays, swift, substring, init

I've written sample data for my view and it looks/works but now i want to replace my sample data with actual data. I've successfully passed in two strings. I'm trying to substring it and replace the wDD and wRead elements of the NamedWeek array with the actual data. Can someone help me how to do that?

my incoming strings look like:
for the wDD -

```
let string1 =  "21|22|23|24|25|26|27"
```

for the wRead -

```
let string2 = "Dan 9|Rev 14|Eze 38|Matt 24|Joel 2|Gen 3|Jer 18"
```

```
struct NamedWeek: Identifiable {
   let wDay: String
   var wDD: String
   var wRead: String
   var id: String { wDay }
}

  var namedWeeks: [NamedWeek] = [
   NamedWeek(wDay: "Sun", wDD: "15", wRead: "Leviticus 26"),
   NamedWeek(wDay: "Mon", wDD: "16", wRead: "Psalm 45"),
   NamedWeek(wDay: "Tue", wDD: "17", wRead: "Test 3"),
   NamedWeek(wDay: "Wed", wDD: "18", wRead: "Test 4"),
   NamedWeek(wDay: "The", wDD: "19", wRead: "Test 5"),
   NamedWeek(wDay: "Fri", wDD: "20", wRead: "Test 6"),
   NamedWeek(wDay: "Sat", wDD: "21", wRead: "Test 7")
     
 ]
```

I was trying to do something like

```
var token = string1.components(separatedBy: "|")
```

and then replacing wDD with token[0] then token[1] or if i could insert a func (don't know if that is possible)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Note the bad code after `var id: String` and the variable below, what is that supposed to be? Please fix it. And also explain how `NamedWeek` is supposed t one created.

Comment: You left `{ wDay }` and where does the value for `wRead` come from in your example?

Comment: Right now wRead  is loaded with test data. What I want to do is replace it with the actual substring of the string2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split by the `|` character, zip the arrays together, then append it to `namedWeeks`.

Code:

```
let string1 =  "21|22|23|24|25|26|27"
let string2 = "Dan 9|Rev 14|Eze 38|Matt 24|Joel 2|Gen 3|Jer 18"

let zipped = zip(string1.split(separator: "|"), string2.split(separator: "|"))
let weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

var namedWeeks = [NamedWeek]()
for (index, element) in zipped.enumerated() {
    namedWeeks.append(NamedWeek(wDay: weekdays[index], wDD: String(element.0), wRead: String(element.1)))
}

print(namedWeeks)
```

Comment: Thank you! I would never  figured that without your knowledge

Comment: @abbey Great, just mark it as accepted so others can more easily find this in the future too :)